# Добавление элементов в список, который находится в объекте

Tags: c#

как добавить в объект `MatrixHolder`, в котором находится `List<int>` элементы из цикла?

```
List<MatrixHolder> matrix = new List<MatrixHolder>();
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

  public void addMat(int length, string name)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < (length); i++) {
            Console.Write($"диапазон {i+1}: ");
            dip = Console.ReadLine();
            int myInt;
            bool isNumerical = int.TryParse(dip, out myInt);
            numbers.Add(myInt);
        }
        matrix.Add(new MatrixHolder { Name = Console.ReadLine(), Numbers = ?????(сюда нужно добивать элементы списка numbers  ) });
```

Comment: А в чем проблема? `Numbers = numbers` не работает что ли?

Comment: а как потом даними оттуда управлять? при виводе вот что будет: [2] matrices[addmat, System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Int32]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы создаете новый объект, то `new MatrixHolder { Name = Console.ReadLine(), Numbers = myInt }`, если объект уже существует, то `matrixHolder.Numbers.AddRange(myInt)`.